# Flink: job fails when one TaskManager is OOM?

Tags: apache-flink

I was running the Flink 1.8 WordCount example job on Kubernetes, I noticed a behavior. Sometimes, a TaskManager pod gets `OOMKilled` and restarted (it is not a concern for now) but the whole job fails, the JobManager log shows `The assigned slot XXX was removed`.

My question is, why does the whole job fail? Is there a way that I can configure Flink to make the job more tolerant to transient TaskManager failures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Flink's fault tolerance mechanism is based on periodic checkpoints and can guarantee exactly-once state consistency, i.e., after recovering from a failure, the state is consistent and the same as if the failure never happened (assuming deterministic application logic of course).

In order to achieve this, Flink takes consistent snapshots of the application's state (so-called checkpoints) in regular intervals. In case of a failure, the whole application is reset to the latest competed checkpoint. For that, Flink (until Flink 1.8) always restarts the whole application. A failure is any reason that terminates a worker process, including application failure, JVM OOM, killed container, hardware failure, etc.

In Flink 1.9 (released a week ago, see [announcement](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/08/22/release-1.9.0.html)), Flink adds so-called *failover regions* (see [here](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/08/22/release-1.9.0.html#fine-grained-batch-recovery-flip-1)), which can reduce the number restarted tasks. For continuous streaming applications, this only applies if the application does not have a shuffle (keyBy, broadcast, partition, ...) operation. In that case, only the affected pipeline is restarted and all other pipelines continue processing data.

Comment: If I submit my job through flink CLI, does restarting the whole job transparent to the CLI? or I have to resubmit it? What I observed is that, the CLI exits with non-0, I have to resubmit.

Comment: Actually, I saw this error message in log: Could not restart the job WordCount Example (5a503e62333d2d82021547ccb9a4bcc6) because the restart strategy prevented it.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to see you here, I'm reading your book on Flink, I learned a lot from it, great job!

Answer (score 1):

Running Flink jobs you should do a capacity plan previously, otherwise, you will meet the **OOM** problems frequently, in kubernetes environment you should calculate how many memories your job will cost and set the **resources.limits.memory** of your deployment higher than it as well as the **resources.requests.memory**, if the **resources.requests.memory** is much lower than your job actually cost your Pod will be fall in **Evicted** state this will cause your job to fail as well.

Answer (score 0):

A container in a Pod may fail due to number of reasons like process in it exited with a non-zero exit code, or the container was killed for exceeding a memory limit

You can use the Jobs specification

```
.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "OnFailure"
```

So using this pod will stay in the system and container will re-run.

For more information on also check official job documentation : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/